# Migrate one method to System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I added NewtonsoftJson as middleware in .net core 3.1. I would love to move over to new System.Text.Json serializer.

I can´t just jump over but is there way to use the one from System.Text.Json in one method some how. More or less it is one that I need to speed up.

Added:
I have in startup

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

My migration proplem is that I can not just change this to System.Text.Json all at once. So if I could change one controller or just one method in controller to use System.Text.Json version that would solve my problem.

Comment: I have no idea *what* you are trying to migrate because you have not included an example. Please see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to) on migrating from Newtonsoft to System.Text.

Comment: See [System.Text.Json Reference Loop Handling](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29900) - note though that the milestone for release is Net Core 5.0..

Comment: _is there way to use the one from System.Text.Json in one method some how. More or less it is one that I need to speed up_ - you can probably use any library you want, as long as you're explicit about it. Maybe add some details about this to your question?

Comment: Incidentally, [this is the spec for the ReferenceHandling in System.Text.Json in Net Core 5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/docs/ReferenceHandling_spec.md)

Comment: See also the current migration guide *[How to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json: Scenarios that JsonSerializer currently doesn't support : Preserve object references and handle loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#preserve-object-references-and-handle-loops)* which states that `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` is not currently implemented.

Answer (score 35):

Starting with .Net 6, System.Text.Json supports ignoring circular references and can be used like this

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(options => {options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;});
```

See here for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently implemented in .Net 3.1.  The current migration guide *[How to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json: Scenarios that JsonSerializer currently doesn't support : Preserve object references and handle loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#preserve-object-references-and-handle-loops)* states:

> `Newtonsoft.Json` also has a `ReferenceLoopHandling` setting that lets you ignore circular references rather than throw an exception.
>
> [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) only supports serialization by value and throws an exception for circular references.

See also the github issue *[System.Text.Json Reference Loop Handling #29900](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29900#issuecomment-502955776)* where this is stated to be a "known limitation" - but there is a current milestone for release which is .Net Core 5.0.  The proposed specification is here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/docs/ReferenceHandling_spec.md