# Self-referencing loop ASP.NET Core 7 & EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 and EF Core. This is my `User` class. A user can have a manager of type `User`. This causes a referencing loop. I want `Manager` to be serialized and ignore `Manager.Manager`.

```cs
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public required string Matricule { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public required string Username { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public required string Email { get; set; }

    public string? PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public required Role Role { get; set; }

    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public User? Manager { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<GroupUser>? GroupUsers { get;} = new();

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Group>? Groups { get;} = new();
}
```

This is what it looks like:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "matricule": "1",
    "name": "Admin",
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@admin.com",
    "passwordHash": null,
    "role": "Admin",
    "managerId": 4,
    "manager": {
      "id": 4,
      "matricule": "3",
      "name": "Director",
      "username": "director",
      "email": "director@director.com",
      "passwordHash": null,
      "role": "Director",
      "managerId": 1,
      "manager": {
        "id": 1,
        "matricule": "0",
        "name": "Super Admin",
        "username": "superadmin",
        "email": "superadmin@admin.com",
        "passwordHash": null,
        "role": "SuperAdmin",
        "managerId": 3,
        "manager": {
          "id": 3,
          "matricule": "2",
          "name": "User",
          "username": "user",
          "email": "user@user.com",
          "passwordHash": null,
          "role": "User",
          "managerId": 1,
          "manager": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-08-06T06:03:42.1715292",
          "updatedAt": null
        },
        "createdAt": "2023-08-06T06:03:41.704061",
        "updatedAt": null
      },
      "createdAt": "2023-08-06T06:03:42.0137132",
      "updatedAt": null
    },
    "createdAt": "2023-08-06T06:03:41.8576385",
    "updatedAt": null
  },
```

I had to implement a for loop and select everything except manager which is a bad solution.

Comment: You should create a DTO and return it instead of returning the whole model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate one method to System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030909/migrate-one-method-to-system-text-json)

Comment: @BagusTesa I've tried that already and unfortunately, it didn't work out.

Comment: *"This causes a referencing loop"* - and **yet** your json does not show any self reference.

Comment: you could use DTO as suggested previously, use [custom serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0), or [limit the maximum depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth?view=net-7.0) of the json.